# How to invoke a user's function properly from a data step with SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm new to SAS and I would like to generate a simple graph according to a variable's value.
I have wrote:

```
%MACRO generate_bar_plot();
%proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
  %hbar smoking_status /
    response=ageatdeath
    stat=mean;
%run;
%MEND;

%MACRO generate_scatter_plot();
proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
title "Height and Weight";
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
  scatter x=height y=weight;
run;
%MEND;
      
        
data _null_;
  array graph_types[4] $10 ('scatter_plot','bar_plot','line_plot','dropline_plot');

  plot_type_idx = rand("integer", 1, 4);

  plot_type = graph_types(plot_type_idx);
      
  select (plot_type);
  when ('scatter_plot') do;
      put "Scatter plot!!";
          %generate_scatter_plot();
  end;
  when ('bar_plot') do;
      put "Bar plot!!";
          %generate_bar_plot();
    end;
    otherwise  put "last ";
  end;
```

I keep getting errors such as:
"There was 1 unclosed DO block."
and
"There was 1 unclosed select block."

Can someone please demonstrate what is the correct approach to resolve this issue. should I use either macro or function and if so can someone share and demonstrate a good practice how to implement this in SAS.

Thank you

Comment: It is not at all clear what code you are trying to generate.  What does the source dataset that has the variable PLOT_TYPE look like?  What does does the dataset (or datasets)  that you want to plot look like?  How are the two related?  Show two example observations of the dataset with the PLOT_TYPE variable and the resulting programs you want to run for those two observations. Describe what part of the code needs to change to make other plots.

Comment: Is the question how to create a macro that will run different plots bases on different inputs to the macro?  You could change the macro to accept the dataset name and or the variable names as parameters and use the values of those parameters to generate the SAS code you want to run.  Or is the question how to generate calls to macros that you already have working?

Comment: What is the purpose of the confusing data step?  Why is it generating a random number?

Comment: Macros are not synonymous with functions. It's more code generation process.

Comment: @Tom has explained how you are mixing scopes of `DATA` step and macro in an incorrect way.  Additionally, the code in original post is incorrect, snippet such as `%proc sgplot`, you wouldn't put `%` before `proc`.  Same for `%hbar` and `%run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro is not a "function". The macro pre-processor passes the modified text of your program on to SAS itself to execute.  When you execute a macro any text it emits becomes part of your program.

So you tried to run code like:

```
data ...
  when ('scatter_plot') do;
    put "Scatter plot!!";
proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
  title "Height and Weight";
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
    scatter x=height y=weight;
run;
  end;
  ...
run;
```

As soon as SAS sees the start of the new PROC step it knows you have reached the end of the data step you wanted to run.  So it complains because you never completed the data step definition before trying to start running the procedure.

If you want to use data to generate code you could use CALL EXECUTE to push code onto the stack to run after the current data step finishes.  Make sure to use single quotes around stings with macro code.  Add %NRSTR() macro function so the macro call itself is pushed onto the stack, instead of the code it emits.

So if you have dataset like this with four observations:

```
data have ;
  input plot_type $20.;
cards;
scatter_plot
bar_plot
line_plot
dropline_plot
;
```

You could use a data step to read in that data and generate a separate macro call for each observation that will run after the data step finishes.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%generate_',plot_type,')()'));
run;
```

So you will see in the SAS log lines like that this that show the code SAS is running as a result of CALL EXECUTE() pushing those strings onto the stack to run.

```
+ %generate_scatter_plot()
+ %generate_bar_plot()
+ %generate_line_plot()
+ %generate_dropline_plot()
```

And if the MPRINT option is on then the SAS log will also show the actual SAS code that the macros generated. So lines like:

```
MPRINT(GENERATE_BAR_PLOT):   proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
MPRINT(GENERATE_BAR_PLOT):   title "Smoking Status";
MPRINT(GENERATE_BAR_PLOT):   hbar smoking_status / response=ageatdeath stat=mean;
MPRINT(GENERATE_BAR_PLOT):   run;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom for replying and explaining the difference between macro to Function.  There is no need to generate a code, I would like to simply invoke the corresponding function, each function is a simple function which will plot a different type of plot. how can I do it? a simple example will do it. Thank you again.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense.  To execute the macro just call it.  To execute it conditionally you might use macro code like %IF/%THEN/%DO, but that would require something like a macro variable that the %IF could test.  To execute it conditionally based on data in a dataset then use what I showed in a data step. Or use the data step to create a text file with the SAS code (including macro calls) that you can run by using the %INCLUDE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CALL EXECUTE to get what you need.

Modifying your posted code:

```
data _null_;
  array graph_types[4] $10 ('scatter_plot','bar_plot','line_plot','dropline_plot');

  plot_type_idx = rand("integer", 1, 4);

  plot_type = graph_types(plot_type_idx);

  if plot_type ='scatter_plot' then call execute('%generate_scatter_plot()');
  else if plot_type = 'bar_plot' then call execute('%generate_bar_plot()');
  else put 'Last';

run;
```